# Not repeat the same data

Tags: sql, t-sql

The idea is to not repeat the same value in the Supervisor column, as shown in the images.

```
select e.Name as Employee, s.Name as Supervisor 
from Employee e, Employee s  
where e.Employee_Supervisor = 2 and s.id = 2
```

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTh3g.jpg)

[I need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ3zY.jpg)

Comment: While it is technically possible to produce output like from SQL alone, this kind of requirement is really the responsibility of the presentation layer. Do you have the option to solve your issue there instead?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and usable data make it much easier for us to help you. Pictures of data aren't very helpful.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this should probably be done by the presentation layer, but. . .

```
select 
    e.Name AS Employee, 
    case when row_number() over (partition by s.Name order by e.Name)=1 
        then s.Name else '' end AS Supervisor 
from Employee e, Employee s  
where e.Employee_Supervisor=2 AND s.id=2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6e91f/4)

Comment: You should ensure the sort order with a final `ORDER BY`, otherwise this can be returned in any order...